# Google apps script error DriveApp not defined in JavaScript

Tags: google-apps-script

a little help if possible.
In a Google Apps Script web application I have an error (DriveApp is not defined) in the following code in the JavaScript.html file:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function(){
    var runner = google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    runner.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getData()
});
```

...

```
var searchParams = "Parametri ricerca";
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchParams);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
 var file = files.next();
 var fileName = file.getName());
 var fileUrl = file.getUrl());
}
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can not use the Apps Script classes such as `DriveApp` from inside JavaScript files. You must use `google.script.run` to call an Apps Script method which uses it.*

#### Code Example:

**JavaScript:**

```
function callGAS {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(doSomething).getFileUrl()
}

function doSomething(fileUrl) {
  console.log(fileUrl) //or whatever you want to do with it
}
```

**Apps Script:**

```js
function getFileUrl() {
  var searchParams = "Parametri ricerca";
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchParams);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
     var file = files.next();
     var fileName = file.getName());
     var fileUrl = file.getUrl());
  }
  return fileUrl // or whatever
}
```

#### References:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)